# predicate logic proof (existential quantifiers)

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble with this proof. I have been working on this for the past 4 days and am not clearer. I get to a point and then it fails. I'm testing it in Fitch.

Premise: ∃x(¬P(x) Ʌ ¬Q(x))
Conclusion: ∃x(¬P(x) Ʌ Q(x))

Premise - there exists some object x, which does not have the property of P and which does not have the property of Q. 
OR - there is exists some object which is notP and notQ. 
Thus, show that for x, if it is notP and notQ, then it is notP and Q

Number of options I tried includes:
starting off with the negation of the desired conclusion and then try to show a contradiction - so ¬(¬P(x) Ʌ Q(x))
I have also tried with starting with the premise as the assumption, then trying to get to the result.

I can see that it should be provable, but stuck on getting there. 
If there exists an object which is notP and notQ, then there should be another object is is notP and Q. So I tried to shows that it can be
P Ʌ (¬Q V Q)

Without having Q, how do I get from notQ to Q

There has been some atrocious attempts showing (¬P Ʌ Q) → Q as well as showing that (¬P Ʌ Q) → ¬Q and then trying to show a contradiction.

[example attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B11mv.jpg)

[example attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5wA9.jpg)

Can someone possibly suggest where I am going wrong, or even suggest a good starting point?

Comment: this is a bit confusing. You are using the quantifier again at the conclusion. So, potentially we could have $$\exists x : \neg P(x)\land\neg Q(x)\Longrightarrow \exists y : \neg P(y)\land Q(y) $$ or is it $$\exists x\left (\neg P(x)\land\neg Q(x)\Longrightarrow \neg P(x)\land Q(x)\right ) $$

Comment: Premise: ∃x(¬P(x) Ʌ ¬Q(x)) Conclusion: ∃x(¬P(x) Ʌ Q(x))

I just realized I wasted 4 days of my time trying to prove an incorrect conclusion. 

The correct conclusion should be (i missed a set of brackets):
Premise: ∃x(¬P(x) Ʌ ¬Q(x)) Conclusion: ∃x(¬(P(x) Ʌ Q(x)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to prove it, since the hypothesis can be true, but the conclusion false.

For example, suppose $P(x),Q(x)$ are always false.